# how to make the parent active when the child of the parent is chosen

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have a header with a menu with dropdowns also a mega dropdown. I merged so far to make the parent highlighted but when a child is clicked than it doesn't work. I have searched and tried everything I could find, but no luck sofar. I have this:  in the top of the header and on every dropdown link: ", that works perfectly for the parent but again the child of the parent won't make the parent to be active. here is a example of the dropdown I have:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle <?= ($activePage == 'Link1') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link1</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="dropdown-item"  <?= ($activePage == 'Link2') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link2</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item <?= ($activePage == 'Link3') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link3</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a class="dropdown-item <?= ($activePage == 'Link4') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link4</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item <?= ($activePage == 'Link5') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="dropdown-item"  <?= ($activePage == 'Link6') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link6</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item <?= ($activePage == 'Link7') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link7</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a class="dropdown-item <?= ($activePage == 'Link8') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link8</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item <?= ($activePage == 'Link9') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link9</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="dropdown-item <?= ($activePage == 'Link10') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link10</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item <?= ($activePage == 'Link11') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link11</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a class="dropdown-item <?= ($activePage == 'Link12') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link12</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item <?= ($activePage == 'Link13') ? 'active':''; ?>" href="#">Link13</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

How can I make it work with php or can't that not be done at all????

Comment: is this probably a javaScript question? for debugging, forward a given $activePage var to your template to prove the css is working so far.

Answer (score 0):

looks like bootstrap. Here an example of javascript

//APP/assets/js/app.js
import '../css/nav.scss';

```
// Need jQuery? Install it with "yarn add jquery", then uncomment to require it.
const $ = require('jquery');
import 'bootstrap'; //add functions to jQuery
//uncomment to support legacy code
global.$ = $;

//navigation active class settings
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        var current_page_URL = location.href;

        $("a").each(function () {

            if ($(this).attr("href") !== "#") {
                var target_URL = $(this).prop("href");

                if (target_URL == current_page_URL) {
                    $('nav a').parents('li, ul').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');

                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    });
});
```

//APP/templates/base.html.twig

```
...
{% block javascripts %}
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Unfortunate it isn't working for me, and I am still on a quest to make this work. I have searched the web for so long now and maybe a if else statement in the php might help. But I have no idea on how to it since I am a novice on this subject.

Comment: no problem. To mark the actual page, usual technique is to use javaScript. Therefore, you have to install ie jQuery. You can do so by Symfony's WebEncore, by node.js or directly as a link in your header. The script above, will be excuted on any http request, so to say on any link, the user will click on. It will evaluate the actual href and find the node of the HTML dom, to change the color or anything else by putting a css class to the wanted element. Of course, you need to provide the class by your css file.
CONCLUSION: jQuery, css, javaScript edit to your needs, linking scripts

Comment: jQuery is already installed and I have tried everything I could find, but nothing seems to work. I split the header nav so I only have to alter it once instead on every page, and that always worked

Comment: Do you use the dev tools plugIn for your browser? You can look up for javaScript errors by using it. I had recently an issue with the bootstrap toogle bar (the burger link on mobiles). By reverting jQuery to 3.4.1 I could solve this problem.

Comment: I have jQuery 3.4.1 installed and still it won't work unfortunately

Comment: add your complete dependencies eg javaScript and the side of your javaScript bindung in your description. Do not forget your jQuery binding ... webencore?